# Networking with VMware, physical adapters and iSCSI

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, iscsi

New VMware user here, setting up my first environment. I have an ESXi host that has four physical NiCs (NiC0, NiC1, NiC2, NiC3).

I have installed ESXi, the VCVA appliance, and several VMs successfully. They are connected to the local storage currently, but I want to connect to our iSCSI SAN.

Physically NiC0 and NiC1 are connected to our regular network switch. NiC2 and NiC3 are connected to our iSCSI network, which is a separate network.
So what I have done is set NiC0 and NiC1 as active for the management network on the ESXi host. I left NiC2 and NiC3 unchecked.

When I use the vSphere client to create the iSCSI connection, it can't see NiC2 or NiC3. Do I need to enable all four NiCs to be able to use them in vSphere?

If I enable NiC2 and NiC3, they say they are disconnected, because they are connected to our iSCSI network and have no regular network connection.

Am I way off track here?

Comment: Do you want the VMs to connect directly to the iSCSI storage or ESX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create another vSwitch to contain your iSCSI ports. This is separate from the vSwitch you created that holds your management and virtual machine traffic:

Something like:

[image]

Once you get past this point, the process is straightforward.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I knew I was missing something!

Comment: Also note that depending on how your storage network and target are configured, you might want to be using port binding.  See [here](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2038869) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you didn'tsetup the vSwitches for iSCSI using NIC2 and NIC3.

If not...

See here for information on the basics to get you started:

[Configuring software iCSI setup](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008083)

and their Youtube video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=FzXYUzYTJVE

The information is for v4 but will get you in the right direction.

EDIT:  better walkthrough video for v5 here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mu-HyD3E3cw

Comment: Instead of providing just links, you should provide at least a brief summary of the actions required.